# Set OnClickListener off and then on

Tags: android, button

I am setting the OnClickListener off after the user has clicked on the button.

```
confirm.setOnClickListener(null);
```

This makes the button unclickable but I want it to be clickable after the user has clicked another button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just set

`confirm.setClickable(false);` to disable and `confirm.setClickable(true)` to enable it again.

[See Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean))

Comment: Similarly, if the user should be able to tell that clicking the button will do nothing until they do something else, you can disable it with confirm.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 3):

Simply

```
confirm.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
```

Where `myOnClickListener` is your `OnClickListener` that you used before! This line of code would need to go in the `OnClickListener` for the 're-activation' button.