# Disabling onclickListener for a memory matching game for android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to make a memory match game for android. I have the game working but with one bug. When the user taps the second button, the game uses a handler to a pause for 1 seconds to allow user to see the match and then resets the buttons, to try again. But within that 1 second pause the user is able to click another button and this screws up the game logic creating problems in the detection. I want to be able to disable onclicklistener for all buttons. I am trying to do this by using a boolean check, but it is not seeming to work. Please help, I am still a beginner with android. Thanks!!

secondScreen.java:

```
package eagle.abhishekravi.abhishek.eagle;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.util.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity;



public class secondScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

//drawables
int res[] = new int[] {R.drawable.brownbars,R.drawable.centeredorangedot, R.drawable.dots, R.drawable.greenlines, R.drawable.lightbulb, R.drawable.orangedots, R.drawable.orangelines, R.drawable.tree, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.yellowwithred, R.drawable.brownbars,R.drawable.centeredorangedot,
        R.drawable.dots, R.drawable.greenlines, R.drawable.lightbulb, R.drawable.orangedots, R.drawable.orangelines, R.drawable.tree, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.yellowwithred};
int lay1, lay2, shuffleCount = 0, gameCount = 0;
ImageButton first, second;

LinearLayout layout;
boolean isClickable = true;

ImageButton b1;
ImageButton b2;
ImageButton b3;
ImageButton b4;
ImageButton b5;
ImageButton b6;
ImageButton b7;
ImageButton b8;
ImageButton b9;
ImageButton b10;
ImageButton b11;
ImageButton b12;
ImageButton b13;
ImageButton b14;
ImageButton b15;
ImageButton b16;
ImageButton b17;
ImageButton b18;
ImageButton b19;
ImageButton b20;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    Intent activityThatCalled = getIntent();

    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    //initialize all buttons in game
    b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    b6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b6);
    b7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b7);
    b8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b8);
    b9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    b10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    b11 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b11);
    b12 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b12);
    b13 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b13);
    b14 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b14);
    b15 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b15);
    b16 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b16);
    b17 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b17);
    b18 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b18);
    b19 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b19);
    b20 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.b20);

    iconRandomizer();



};


public void randomCheck(ImageButton btn, int image) {

    if (gameCount < 2) {
        gameCount++;
        if (gameCount == 1) {
            first = btn;
            lay1 = image;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(gameCount);
            isClickable = false;
            second = btn;
            lay2 = image;


            if (lay1 != lay2) {


                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        buttonEnabler(false);
                           first.setImageResource(R.color.material_blue_grey_800);
                        second.setImageResource(R.color.material_blue_grey_800);
                        first.setEnabled(true);
                        second.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                }, 1000);


            }
            gameCount = 0;
           // isClickable = true;

        }

    }
    isClickable = true;
}

static void shuffleArray(int[] ar)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Simple swap
        int a = ar[index];
        ar[index] = ar[i];
        ar[i] = a;
    }
}




public void iconRandomizer() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(res[i]);


    shuffleArray(res);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println(res[i]);

    if (isClickable) {
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);
        b10.setOnClickListener(this);
        b11.setOnClickListener(this);
        b12.setOnClickListener(this);
        b13.setOnClickListener(this);
        b14.setOnClickListener(this);
        b15.setOnClickListener(this);
        b16.setOnClickListener(this);
        b17.setOnClickListener(this);
        b18.setOnClickListener(this);
        b19.setOnClickListener(this);
        b20.setOnClickListener(this);
        isClickable = true;
    }
}




public void onClick(View v){
    System.out.println(isClickable);

    if (isClickable) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.b1:
                if (isClickable) {
                    Log.d("mytag", "isclickable is true");
                    b1.setImageResource(res[0]);
                    b1.setEnabled(false);
                    randomCheck(b1, res[0]);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.b2:
                if (isClickable) {
                    b2.setImageResource(res[1]);
                    b2.setEnabled(false);
                    randomCheck(b2, res[1]);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.b3:
                b3.setImageResource(res[2]);
                b3.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b3, res[2]);

                break;
            case R.id.b4:
                b4.setImageResource(res[3]);
                b4.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b4, res[3]);

                break;
            case R.id.b5:
                b5.setImageResource(res[4]);
                b5.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b5, res[4]);

                break;
            case R.id.b6:
                b6.setImageResource(res[5]);
                b6.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b6, res[5]);

                break;
            case R.id.b7:
                b7.setImageResource(res[6]);
                b7.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b7, res[6]);

                break;
            case R.id.b8:
                b8.setImageResource(res[7]);
                b8.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b8, res[7]);

                break;
            case R.id.b9:
                b9.setImageResource(res[8]);
                b9.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b9, res[8]);

                break;
            case R.id.b10:
                b10.setImageResource(res[9]);
                b10.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b10, res[9]);

                break;
            case R.id.b11:
                b11.setImageResource(res[10]);
                b11.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b11, res[10]);

                break;
            case R.id.b12:
                b12.setImageResource(res[11]);
                b12.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b12, res[11]);

            case R.id.b13:
                b13.setImageResource(res[12]);
                b13.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b13, res[12]);

                break;
            case R.id.b14:
                b14.setImageResource(res[13]);
                b14.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b14, res[13]);

            case R.id.b15:
                b15.setImageResource(res[14]);
                b15.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b15, res[14]);

                break;
            case R.id.b16:
                b16.setImageResource(res[15]);
                b16.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b16, res[15]);

                break;
            case R.id.b17:
                b17.setImageResource(res[16]);
                b17.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b17, res[16]);

                break;
            case R.id.b18:
                b18.setImageResource(res[17]);
                b18.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b18, res[17]);

                break;
            case R.id.b19:
                b19.setImageResource(res[18]);
                b19.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b19, res[18]);

                break;
            case R.id.b20:
                b20.setImageResource(res[19]);
                b20.setEnabled(false);
                randomCheck(b20, res[19]);


                break;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >


<ImageButton
   android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"


/>



        />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"

        />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"

        />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"


        />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"


        />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b10"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b11"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b12"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b13"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"


        />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b14"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b15"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b16"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    >


    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b17"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"


        />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b18"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b19"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        android:id="@+id/b20"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this post?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6750525/3761440)

Comment: Here is another post. That may also helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238209/set-onclicklistener-off-and-then-on

Comment: You could use a Boolean as well inside the OnClick much simpler

Comment: What do you mean by use a Boolean inside OnClick, could you provide an example please? As for the other questions, could I just make all my buttons clickable in xml and then button.setClickable(false) to disable it?

Comment: Fixed it! I just had to change the global variable isClickable to true inside the handler. The handler performs the code inside after the time allocated. Fixed the problem.